# Can't import one of my mongo schema file order.js (model) in a javascript file user.js (controller)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to import a schema file(order.js) inside user.js from "models" folder.
My application gets crashed after saving user.js, it throws an error as follows,
"TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `product.type`, got value "undefined""

In user.js, I have imported order.js as follows,

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const Order = require("../models/order"); //Throws error on this line.
```

But when I comment require("../models/order") line, app starts to perform well.

This is my multiple Schema file (order.js):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Objectid } = mongoose.Schema;

const productCartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: Objectid,
    ref: "Product",
  },
  name: String,
  count: Number,
  price: Number,
});
const ProductCart = mongoose.model("ProductCart", productCartSchema);

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    products: [productCartSchema],
    transactionid: {},
    address: String,
    amount: { type: Number },
    updated: Date,
    user: {
      type: Objectid,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

module.exports = { Order, ProductCart };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on this issue.
The ObjectId in my order.js is not defined. I just replaced it with mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

This solved my issue.